# Django create form wizard from model form

Tags: python, django, django-models

My requirement is to create a form wizard using model form. For example, I have a number of dynamic models, one model has 10 fields and another model have 15 fields. the model form should be split into multiple forms automatically based on fields it contains.

I have tried using **django-form-tools**, but in **django-form-tools** we need to predefine the form classes in **form_list** attribute.

Is there any other alternative to achieve this without manually doing this

Comment: By using forms.ModelForm you have to specify the model the form will use... What do you mean with dynamic models? Can you share some code?

Comment: I am django-mutant. Which create tables dynamically. Based on table id model structure is different. This what I mentioned as dynamic models

Comment: do you have some condition that specify if the model will have some fields or not? You still didn't provide some code! I can't help very much with only this information!